# Stop displaying type cursor when clicked on a toolstrip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Im am making a toolstrip for my windows application in c#,
but when I press on a option of my toolstrip, the type cursor shows up.
It want it to be like a button, when you click on it something the code indicates happens. and not having the type cursor show up

Here is a photo of my problem:

[image]

I've already set `ReadOnly` to `True`, But this only prevents the user from typing in the toolstrip, not removing the type/text cursor.

I've tried `Toolstrip.Cursor.Dispose()`, But it gave me an error that toolstrip had no atribute Cursor. Al tough is should work on textboxes (haven't tried it on textboxes yet, because I have no need for that)

I'm a beginner with c#, but have some experience with python, so please go easy on me.

I expect that When I click on the box, The text/type cursor doesnt appear.

I use visual studio btw. I created the toolstrip in Design mode.

Comment: Does that actually happen when you *run* your app? Because that is design mode behavior.

Comment: @nvoigt Yes, I happens when I run the app in visual studio. Visual studio has a options called start wich compiles the script in a exe form, and then executes it. Then I get that problem

Comment: That is weird. I'm afraid I cannot offer anything beyond "that should not happen". Make sure you actually do run it...

Comment: How did you add the field to the Toolstrip? Can you check what type of object it is? You should be able to see the type near the properties window. There is a Textbox type of toolstrip object - perhaps you added that instead of the button one?

Comment: Thanks both of you for helping but I figured it out. One last quistion: Should I delete the quistion? It is probally irrelevant for other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Created A toolstrip, with a menu item, and In that menu item a textbox.

I shouldn't have created a textbox, but another menu item, and if that was pressed execute some code.

So If I just create a menu item in the toolstrip and create another menu item in the toolstrip, and set `click` to one of my code functions it acts as a button.